# markerclusterer: anchor offset for cluster icons

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm trying to slightly offset cluster icons created by the Google Maps Markerclusterer (V3). Short of modifying the existing code, I can't find a way to do this. Does anybody have an idea?

The Styles object in which you can provide a custom image URL accepts an anchor property, but this is to offset the generated marker item count.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some transparent space to one side of your cluster icon's PNG, so that the part of the icon which you'd like to be centred is actually also centred in your PNG.  This should not increase the weight of your image by more than a few bytes.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. Not the prettiest solution but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to do it is to adjust the `anchorIcon` property like this:

```
var clusterStyles = [
{
    height: 64,
    width: 53,
    anchorIcon: [20, 140]
},
{
    height: 64,
    width: 53,
    anchorIcon: [20, 140]
},
{
    height: 64,
    width: 53,
    anchorIcon: [20, 140]
}
];

var mcOptions = {
    styles: clusterStyles
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Comment: but there is no usage of anchorIcon var name in source code

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer does not work well enough for me - adding transparent space to the icon image can change the way click and hover events behave due to the increased size of the object.

I would use the `anchorIcon` property except it's only available in [Marker Clusterer Plus](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js), not the other [Marker Clusterer](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) plugin (which I'm using).

For those that specifically want to use Marker Clusterer - you can override `ClusterIcon.prototype.getPosFromLatLng_`. The `ClusterIcon` object is global, so we can modify it at the top-level of any script file without messing with the plugin's source code.

This will anchor the marker to the bottom of the icon:

```
ClusterIcon.prototype.getPosFromLatLng_ = function (latlng) {
  var pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(latlng);
  pos.x -= parseInt(this.width_ / 2);
  pos.y -= parseInt(this.height_);
  return pos;
};
```

Comment: @ashleedawg you only need to run this once so that the modified function replaces the original `getPosFromLatLng_`, so I would say put it at the top level of any script file. 

And if you're using Marker Clusterer Plus see the `anchorIcon` solution by @NXT

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code of marcerclusterer.js to support anchorText parameter by modifying following two functions:

```
/**
 * Sets the icon to the the styles.
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.useStyle = function() {
  var index = Math.max(0, this.sums_.index - 1);
  index = Math.min(this.styles_.length - 1, index);
  var style = this.styles_[index];
  this.url_ = style['url'];
  this.height_ = style['height'];
  this.width_ = style['width'];
  this.textColor_ = style['textColor'];
  this.anchor_ = style['anchor'];
  this.anchorText_ = style['anchorText']; //added to support anchorText parameter by Frane Poljak, Locastic
  this.textSize_ = style['textSize'];
  this.backgroundPosition_ = style['backgroundPosition'];
};


/**
 * Adding the cluster icon to the dom.
 * @ignore
 */
ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  this.div_ = document.createElement('DIV');
  if (this.visible_) {
    var pos = this.getPosFromLatLng_(this.center_);
    this.div_.style.cssText = this.createCss(pos);

      ////added to support anchorText parameter by Frane Poljak, Locastic

      if (typeof this.anchorText_ === 'object' && typeof this.anchorText_[0] === 'number' && typeof this.anchorText_[1] === 'number') {
          this.div_.innerHTML = '<span style="position:relative;top:' + String(this.anchorText_[0]) + 'px;left:' + String(this.anchorText_[1]) + 'px;">' + this.sums_.text + '</span>'
      } else this.div_.innerHTML = this.sums_.text;
  } 

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div_);

  var that = this;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, 'click', function() {
    that.triggerClusterClick();
  });
};
```

Comment: This solved my problem. You should create a PR to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

anchor / anchorIcon/ anchorText properties didn't work for me...so I made kind of workaround:

I use `setCalculator()` function to set the cluster text:

https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html

when I am setting the cluster text property I am wrapping the value with `<span>`,
something like this:

```
markerCluster.setCalculator(function (markers) {
   return {
      text: '<span class="myClass">' + value+ '</span>',
      index: index                   
   };
});
```

now you can control the cluster label position with ".myClass":

```
span.myClass{
   position: relative;
   top: -15px;
   .....
}
```